# Creating new Apache config file from PHP

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, apache2

my fellow programmers

I do have a question about Apache2 and PHP.
Well, right now I'm trying to make a script that will create new "virtual hosts" from the PHP script, without using `sudo` command inside PHP.

The solutions with `echo passwd | /usr/bin/sudo -S command` are not really secure, and I won't use something like that.
Also, I've found the solution with a `www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:` is as well not a solution.

Can someone please shed some light, which is the best solution for that, and what are the best protection measures? In case I need to use a `sudo` inside a PHP.

Of course, that script will have some part a making a new directory, cp-ing new site files inside a dir, etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this is a really bad plan for this, but somehow this is the best solution for this.

To do this in a proper way, I'll use the bash script, and I'll call that script from PHP.

```
    $output = shell_exec("sudo /path/to/script/script.sh $SiteName $Domain");
```

**script.sh**

```sh
    #! /bin/bash

    #First parameter given by calling the script
    sitename=$1

    #Second parameter given by calling the script
    domain=$2
   
    #Directorium where are stored files of the web app
    dirlocation="/var/www/$sitename"
    
    #Creating a new directorium
    mkdir $dirlocation

    #Copying the defoult files of app to the just created dir
    cp -R /var/www/someapp/* $dirlocation
    
    #Creating the new configurationg file for Apache and VHost
    vhost_script="/etc/apache2/sites-available/$sitename.conf"
    cat > "${vhost_script}" << EOF
    <VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName $domain
        DocumentRoot $dirlocation

        <Directory $dirlocation>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
        </Directory>
    </VirtualHost>
    EOF

    #Enabling the site in Apache
    a2ensite $sitename.conf
   
    #Reloading the Apache
    systemctl reload apache2.service
```

Also in order to do this from a PHP, I need to give `www-data` permission for running only that script with sudo.
To do so open the `sudoers` file (`sudo visudo /etc/sudoers`) and add the following line

```
www-data ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /path/to/script/script.sh
```

I know this is maybe not the best solution, but this is what I've found for this purpose.

*Disclaimer: This is only a showcase of how to do this, also the bash script here is a really simple one.*

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a incredible bad plan security wise. You have to edit apache config files and then reload or restart the apache2 server.

You could do it by editing the sudoers file to give the www-data user the right to reload apache and add a vhost configuration to apache that the www-data user has writing rights on.

Second option is to fake vhosts via php:

```
<?php
switch ($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']) {
  case "site1.example.com" :
     require_once 'some_config_for_site_1.php';
     // load scripts from site1 folder.
     break;
  case "site2.example.com" :
     require_once 'some_config_for_site_2.php';
     // load scripts from site1 folder.
     break;
  default:
     http_response_code(404);
     break;
}
```

Comment: Tbh, I've considered that solution with a PHP fake vhost. but it won't work in this case, because of some rewrite rules. But I've got some idea, with FTP(sFTP) which one can be really good. And that is to enter the password before running a script, which one will do everything via FTP. but there is again a problem with reloading a2(and I can include some "not wise script `echo $_POST['passwd'] | /usr/bin/sudo -S command`"for a2ensite and reload a2). So probably that's gonna be a solution, inputting a  password right before running a script, without remembering it. But still don't like it...

Comment: There is no secure maintainable solution here to arrange this from php directly. You could look at seclib and arrange this via an SSH connection (instead of sFTP) with a password prompt to the user. Another option is to switch to for example AWS and call something like cloudformation to duplicate the site.